# Call a nested function through a global function?

Tags: python, function, nested

I am new to Python and am trying to make a simple game with several chapters. I want you to be able to do different things depending on the chapter, but always be able to e.g. check your inventory. This is why I have tried using nested functions.

Is it possible to create a global function which acts differently depending on what chapter I am in, while still having certain options available in all chapters or should I perhaps restructure my code significantly?

I get the following error code:

> ```
> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 21, in
> > <module>
> >     chapter1()   File "test.py", line 19, in chapter1
> >     standstill()   File "test.py", line 4, in standstill
> >     localoptions() NameError: name 'localoptions' is not defined
> ```

I understand that the global function doesn't identify a nested function. Is there any way to specify this nested function to the global function?

```
def standstill():
    print("What now?")
    print("Press A to check inventory")
    localoptions()
    choice = input()
    if choice == "A":
        print("You have some stuff.")
    else:
        localanswers()

def chapter1():
    def localoptions():
        print("Press B to pick a flower.")

    def localanswers():
        if choice == "B":
            print("What a nice flower!")

    standstill()

chapter1()
```

Comment: Why use nested functions for this in the first place? Also, please share the entire error emssage.

Comment: Name lookups occur in the scope where functions are *defined*, not called.

Comment: Nested functions are not the way most people organize this sort of functionality. Typically, the methods are: 1. external data files (e.g. JSON, XML, ...) containing the actual story content; the code only deals with *game logic*, not story. 2. separate classes... `chapter1 = Chapter(); chapter1.localoptions()` 3. separate files/modules. `chapter1.localoptions()`.

Comment: Typo in my comment above, this is what it should read: _Also, please share the entire error message._

Answer (score 0):

I used classes as Mateen Ulhaq suggested and solved it. Thank you! This is an example of a scalable system for the game.

**(I am new to Python and this might not be the best way, but this is how I solved it now.)**

```
class chapter1:
    option_b = "Pick a flower."

def standstill():
    print("What do you do now?")
    print("A: Check inventory.")
    if chapter1active == True:
        print("B: " + chapter1.option_b)

#Chapter 1
chapter1active = True
standstill()
chapter1active = False
```